# How to Add Styling to Variable?

Tags: jquery, css, variables, styling

How to add style to *text:* '**Season One/Two/Three**'...?
This is the code I'm currently using:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
var data = [
{text: 'Season One', url: "/Season?open=1"},
{text: 'Season Two', url: "/Season?open=2"},
{text: 'Season Three', url: "/Season?open=3"},
{text: 'Season Four', url: "/Season?open=4"},
{text: 'Season Five', url: "/Season?open=5"}
];
$('#SeasonInput').autocomplete(data,
{
formatItem: function(item)
{ 
return item.text;
} 
}).result(function(event, item)
{
location.href = item.url;
});
});
```

I tried `.css({'margin: 0', 'background-color: white'})` and other variants, but with no success.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.css` is wrong. It must be this object: `.css({margin: '0', 'background-color': 'white'})`
(`{key: value, key: value}`, `'` around key can be omitted if it does not contain `-`).

Comment: `$("#SeasonInput").css({margin: '0', 'background-color': 'white'}).autocomplete(data,{formatItem: function(item){ return item.text;} }).result(function(event, item)` it has no effect.

Comment: @Dejan Please edit your question with HTML structure and CSS for `#SeasonInput`

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code .css({'margin: 0', 'background-color: white'}) . try this one $('#SeasonInput').css({margin:0, backgroundColor: 'white'});  . when you make it's property as a object then you need not use double code in name but you need to use double code in value .like this backgroundColor: 'white' . it's simple and smart

Comment: yes . you didn't put code in right place . it should work .  here #SeasonInput by this . did you target right DOM element ? please check your selector

Comment: I put it exactly as `$('#SeasonInput').css({margin:0, backgroundColor: 'white'}).autocomplete(data, ...` but it does not work?

Comment: what error you can see in your browser console ? can you check browser console ?